# How do I remove classes based on a type as you go search filter when text input is empty?

Tags: jquery

I have a working search filter that highlights matching items as text is entered. The problem I'm having is all the items in the list get assigned highlight classes when I the text input is cleared.

What do I need to do to remove all the highlight classes if the text input is empty or just has whitespace?

My current code is based off something I found on this site. I'm not a js/jquery whiz and my attempts to get the classes removed if the text input is empty have been unsuccessful.

```
<script>
    const $input = $("#tagfilter");
    const $items = $(".taglist");

    function filterItems(text) {
      text = text.trim().toLowerCase();

      $items.each(function() {
        const cont = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
        const hasText = cont.includes(text);
        $(this).toggleClass("fw-bold text-light bg-dark rounded p-1", hasText)
      });
    }

    $input.on("input", function() {
      filterItems($(this).val());
    }); 
</script>
```

The #tagfilter is the text input for filtering, and .taglist is assigned to each item in the list.

This is basically how the html looks:

```
<input id="tagfilter" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off">

<div class="taglist">item one</div>
<div class="taglist">item two</div>
<div class="taglist">item three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what all of your classes actually do, I created a simplified set of classes for my answer.

By default I'm hiding the taglist, then I toggle an active class which shows the list.

My answer is to surround the each with an if statement to check if the text isn't empty. If it is empty, remove the active class.

```js
const $input = $("#tagfilter");
const $items = $(".taglist");

function filterItems(text) {
  text = text.trim().toLowerCase();

  if(text != ""){
    $items.each(function() {
      const cont = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
      const hasText = cont.includes(text);
      $(this).toggleClass("active", hasText)
    });
   }
   else{
    $(".taglist.active").removeClass("active")
   }
}

$input.on("input", function() {
  filterItems($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.taglist{display:none}
.taglist.active{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tagfilter" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off">

<div class="taglist">item one</div>
<div class="taglist">item two</div>
<div class="taglist">item three</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it gave me what I needed to get things working.

Comment: "*This wasn't exactly what I was looking for...*" - please consider adding details, such as defining *exactly* what you're looking for, in your question; I know you've posted your own answer already but a clear question helps others offer better answers in future (as JavaScript evolves), and helps those looking for answers to their own - similar - problems.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer above, I was able to do exactly what I wanted with this:

```
    <script>
    const $input = $("#tagfilter");
    const $items = $(".taglist");

    function filterItems(text) {
        text = text.trim().toLowerCase();
        if(text != ""){
            $items.each(function() {
                const cont = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
                const hasText = cont.includes(text);
                $(this).toggleClass("fw-bold text-light bg-dark rounded p-1", hasText)
            });
        }
        else{
            $(".taglist").removeClass("fw-bold text-light bg-dark rounded p-1")
        }
    }

    $input.on("input", function() {
      filterItems($(this).val());
    }); 
</script>
```